# How to use Python as scripting language for Jenkins or other CI?

Tags: python, jenkins, continuous-integration

When defining tasks in Jenkins CI, it is written in Shell. However, I have been using Python as the scripting language (with some dependencies such as typer) in place of Shell. Therefore, I wonder how to run it in Jenkins?

A naive thought is to package a Python with all its dependencies into docker images that are to be run in Jenkins CI. However, that does not sound convenient, because we will have to add Python (and dependencies) for *each and every* docker image to be used in Jenkins which would be a lot.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Typically you would break out your jenkins agents into different sets of nodes where particular nodes have different dependencies installed. The pipeline definitions allow you to set constraints for what types of nodes a job is valid to be run on. Another option is to have docker steps inside the actual pipeline and have docker installed on each agent. That ends up being very flexible because each job can run tasks using custom images managed by your team. https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/

Comment: If you're not too far down the Jenkins rabbit hole, and have some K8S experience, Argo Workflows are an awesome tool for defining CI tasks. I've been using it happily for about a year now, and am continuing to move away from Jenkins, favoring Argo for our CI and async job orchestration tooling.  https://argoproj.github.io/argo-workflows/

Comment: @flakes Thanks! I am not sure whether I understand correctly: I should install python and dependency packages as well as Docker in Jenkins agents, then I can use python as scripting language, and run docker images

Comment: @flakes Argo workflow sounds interesting! But how can I use Python as scripting language when it does everything in containers?

Comment: The scripting language you choose can be set by using a shebang e.g. `sh """#!/usr/bin/env python \n <your script>"""`. In a typical Jenkins pipeline you would need to have python on the agent itself. If you use the `docker` declaration in the pipeline, then you need to have docker on the agent, and python only needs to be in the image. For an Argo approach, you would set python as the command and provide the script as an input. e.g. https://github.com/argoproj/argo-workflows/blob/master/examples/scripts-python.yaml#L26-L33

Comment: In both the declarative Jenkins docker approach, as well as the Argo approach, the main advantage is limiting the dependencies required on the base system to launch the jobs. Having images declared in the pipeline itself, means dependencies can be resolved at task runtime by simply pulling the image. This means when you add new dependencies you only have to change the image name/tag declared, and you avoid the more tedious route of updating jenkins agents or defining new agent node groups which have the required dependencies.

Comment: @flakes Thank you! But the problem is, using docker-based approaches, I have to create an image *with python dependency*. Say I want to run `mvn build`. Then I need an image with maven *and* also with Python and needed python packages inside that image.

Comment: Yes, if you have a script with multiple dependencies then you will need to have an image with those dependencies installed. However, you can break pipelines into multiple steps where each step is executed in a different container. I have pipelines that run CI for Python, Golang, NodeJS, and Java all in one, but each task is defined as a separate step in the pipeline which is configured with the appropriate image containing the required dependencies. This reduces the cardinality of dependencies required in each individual image.

Comment: @flakes Thank you! However the problem is, I use python *as scripting language*. In other words, for example, to build a java app, I have (e.g.) 100 line of python script to run that.

Comment: In that case you will need to maintain images with both your Python and Java dependencies installed. If you're worried about image maintenance, consider tools like [buildpacks](https://buildpacks.io/docs/concepts/) and [kpack](https://github.com/pivotal/kpack) to generate images. These images can then be used in your pipelines. Deciding on creating more generic images vs step specific images will depend on your use-case. For common operations you can re-use images, for more complex tasks they can be custom built solely for the purpose of that task.